# Run and follow remote Python script execution from Django website

Tags: python, django, hpc

I am running a Django website where user can perform some light calculation.
This website is hosted in a Docker container on one of our server.

I would like now to add the ability for the users to run some more complicated simulations from the same website. These simulations will have to run on a dedicated calculation machine (they will run in parallel for a several hours/days) under Ubuntu server in the same network.

- What will be the best way to achieve this? Send the calculation to the calculation serverand send them back automatically to Django?
- How can I follow the status of the calculation (waiting, calculating, finished) from the Django instance?
- Should I use a job scheduler on the calculation server?

This is close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005924/run-script-on-remote-server-from-django-webserver) that was asked in 2014, so there might be more actual solutions.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" depends on lots of local decisions that we can't help with.

Django can use Python `subprocess` to execute any Linux shell command. So once you decide on how to submit a job to the local machine from the command line, you can do it from your server. (Note, it may need a way to specify a linux user corresponding to the Django `request.user`)

You can also provide an API for updating status and returning results to the server. That'll be little different to a regular POST view, possibly with a FileField / request.FILES for sending results files.